# What CMS to use as flexible front end

Tags: database, cms, framework

I am looking for a CMS that can be used as a front end website on an existing database. The database is part of our in-house software package that acts as a server to SmartPhone clients.

The idea is that non-technical users are allowed to put information in this database. Because the application is in constant development there needs to be a high level of flexibility for the content that these users are allowed to input.

I found this kind of flexibility in my personal favorite CMS: Drupal. However, drupal has the disadvantage that the database structure is pretty much static. I would like a CMS that is very loosely coupled to its database structure, because it is highly likely that the db will change in the future.

Any recommendations?

Comment: When choosing a CMS, the first stop should always be http://cmsmatrix.org/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Rubedo](http://www.rubedo-project.org)  : it is a flexible open source CMS with a good interface. I don't think you can switch to a different database technology with it though, but the structure of the database itself is interesting as it uses Mongodb. It's a scalable big-data CMS maintained by a very active team.